# Find GAE Datastore entities by application ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I transferred a bunch of entities from one application to another. For most of them, the "application" part of the entity key got successfully converted from `s~old-app` to `s~new-app`. However, there are some bad apples that didn't get converted, causing new-app to throw errors like `BadRequestError: app s~old-app cannot access app s~new-app's data`.

How can I find these items and fix them?

Comment: Are you storing URL safe keys anywhere?  That would be a likely culprit.  URL safe keys always store an application id, but regular keys do not unless you go out of your way to add the application id.

Comment: I'm using remote_api, which probably passes URL safe keys around.